# Why is my Informatica XML $FileName value being overridden by session?

Tags: informatica

I added the FileName column to my XML target and mapped a value to it from the Expression transformation. This should give me a dynamic file name for every xml file based on the Expression result, but it doesn't work. It is taking the static value from the session 'Output file name' attribute. The Informatica help says that the XML FileName column should override the session 'Output file name' value, but the opposite is happening.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain clearly? So for understood is you are trying to store the file name in the target, but each time same file name is stored. Is that right?

Comment: Well, that should not happen. Double check if you have connected the the Filename port, refreshed the session etc.